# Nuxt 3 Web Worker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, web-worker

My Nuxt 3 app needs to run some possibly heavy string-related calculations so I want to move them in worker:

```js
// /assets/workers/test.ts

// import someStuff from "my-package-in-node_modules"

console.log('Hello from worker!');

onmessage = () => {
    /* Do stuff... */
}
```

This is how I add worker on my Vue page:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
    import MyWorker from "~/assets/workers/test?worker";

    const worker = new MyWorker();
</script>
```

However, when I try to open the page it shows an 500 error followed with `Worker is not defined` message.

My guess is that it fails to create worker on server side and throws an error. So maybe I need to somehow run this part of code only on client side.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you opened SSR (or by default) in `nuxt.config.ts`, `<script setup>` will run on server side. That's why `Worker` is not defined.

You can do like this:

```
onMounted(async () => {
  const MyWorker = await import("~/assets/workers/test?worker");
  const worker = new MyWorker();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Nuxt can't create workers on server side, the worker has to be created on client side:

```js
if (process.client)
{
    const worker = new MyWorker();
}
```